# How do I copy/paste website content WITH formatting

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy-paste website content **with** formatting in Google Chrome? Perhaps an extension that gives such an option?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, Chrome, or any modern browser, when copying your selection, will always copy the HTML (i.e., with formatting). The software you're *pasting* it into, however, need to support this (most office programs do, but you might need to select "Paste Special" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

Still, the browser will only copy the HTML, but not the styles associated with it, so any *indirect* formatting through CSS rules will most likely not be copied and, in fact, it would be very difficult to copy them.

Comment: Exactly. @Volodymyr, where are you trying to paste into?

Comment: Trying to paste it on another tab in the same browser, to another SE site as an answer.

Comment: @Volodymyr That won't ever work, since browser input fields never support formatting, only plain text (unless it's a javascript-based rich edit field, which is not the case for SE sites).

Comment: I see, so only manual formatting is possible, which is pretty time-consuming:(.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites use MarkDown, so I think you should be able to edit an answer/question to access the MarkDown script and paste that into the other Stack Exchange site as an answer.

Comment: The common practice on Stack Exchange is to create the demo on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com), etc, and then add the link in your question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like Stefan said, any browser will copy the html, but you need to paste it into a program that will recognise it.

This is something I've been trying to do today, and there are some great wysiwyg editors you can use:

- [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)
- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php)

I wish there was a preview mode for these, but well, they work!

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome, you can select the text (don't need to be completely precise at this step, as you will need to select again), then `Inspect` (or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>), and then you have options (`Copy Outer HTML`,`Edit as HTML`) to copy the HTML code as the 'text/plain' MIME type the text editor prefers.

That might be an add-on free option if your editing environment (my case too) does not provide proper support for pasting MIME flavors other than plain text.